# Semi Transparent contains of Relative Layout

Tags: android, transparent, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profilepicBlog"
                    android:layout_width="54dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/defimg"
                    app:civ_border_color="#2a30a3"
                    app:civ_border_width="1dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/post_username"
                    android:layout_width="193dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="74dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                    android:text="UserName"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                    android:textColor="#4d5459"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/tools"
                    android:layout_width="37dp"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
                    android:rotation="90"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_image
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/usertime"
                    android:layout_width="193dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/post_username"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/post_username"
                    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#737377"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to make the layout semi transparent in a way that all the backgrounds i.e., the corners of circular imageview, the background of imagebutton and the unused parts of Relative Layout becomes semi transparent. Is there any simple way to do that?

Comment: By Semi-Transparent, do you mean Translucent?

Comment: Yes. I want to make a translucent background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

Each component (A, R, G, B) can take values from 0-255. 85% of 255 = 216. 216 in Hex = D8

Hence, if we consider Translucent Black, then

85% black should be `#D8000000`

Similarly you can give it to any color.

Next, apply it to your rootlayout, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#D8000000" >
```

Try it, Hopefully it should work.

Comment: Thanks! Not only it helped with the problem, I also got the concept.

Comment: You're welcome, Be sure to upvote it too, so that others too can know. :)